# What is this species of green frog found in store-bought flowers in France?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology

Today I found a frog in a big flower composition bought at a french shop (living in Grenoble, south of France).

It started snowing today, and I'd like to keep it until it's warmer outside.

So could someone tell me what species it is ? (To check what it eats and if it's legal to keep it)

Thanks !

[image]

(I'll edit with more pictures if it's needed and if she moves)

Edit :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please update your post with the size of your frog. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a type of green frog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks very much like a [tree frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_frog) of which there are many similar looking species. Without knowing where your flowers came from or more characteristics about the specimen, it'll be difficult to provide an accurate answer*.

One possibility may be the [**European tree frog**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_tree_frog) (*Hyla arborea*).

According to Wikipedia:

> Members of the ***H. arborea*** species complex are the **only representatives of the widespread tree frog family (Hylidae) indigenous to mainland Europe**.

- which is supported by genetic work by [Stöck et al. 2008](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/37675869/Stoeck_etal_2008_lHylaPhylogenyMPE.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1548435155&Signature=TujZMpSN7f5EJGufmNnfzYEYUZA%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DMitochondrial_and_nuclear_phylogeny_of_c.pdf)<sup>1</sup>

**Description** [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_tree_frog#cite_note-Stock-5)]:

- Small (3.2-5 cm in length)
- Slender body shape with long legs and smooth dorsal skin<sup>+</sup>
- Usually green (but variable) with dark brown lateral stripe across eye caudally to groin and whitish ventral skin surface.
- Gripping discs on toes

The range of this species also includes much of France:

[image]

<sup>[Image Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_tree_frog#/media/File:Mapa_Hyla_arborea.png)</sup>

<sup>+</sup> Although the description states this species has *smooth* dorsal skin (possibly like the OP's specimen -- I can't tell for sure), many of the pictures I've seen seem to suggest that the dorsal skin of this species is actually rather *granular*. For example, see [here](https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/cgi/img_query?enlarge=0000+0000+0706+1224).

***Feel free to update your post with additional info and perhaps a better response will be added.**

---

<sup>Citations:</sup>

<sup>**1** Stöck, M., Dubey, S., Klütsch, C., Litvinchuk, S.N., Scheidt, U. and Perrin, N., 2008. Mitochondrial and nuclear phylogeny of circum-Mediterranean tree frogs from the Hyla arborea group. Molecular Phylogenetics and Evolution, 49(3), p.1019.</sup>

Comment: I think the European tree frog is more than a possibility. This looks exactly like one.

Comment: @RHA I agree it looks like a pretty good candidate. My concern came from the skin texture. Most images I've seen seem to suggest *H. arborea* actually has rather granular dorsal skin, whereas the OP's specimen looks to have smooth dorsal skin (which matches the description I quoted). This lack of clarity was the only reason I shied from giving a definitive response.

Comment: I think it looks smooth when the skin is wet. I've seen the Europeam tree frog a number of times in the wild and this looks like one. Besides, there is no realistic alternative in Europe.

Comment: @RHA Ok cool -- fair enough. My only thought was that perhaps some nonnative had been transported with the flowers. I appreciate the first-hand knowledge since its quite hard to catch a glimpse of one across the Atlantic :p